# Menu options doesn't display in xconfig

Tags: buildroot

I'm using Buildroot 2020.02 to compile an embedded OS.

When I try to change the toolchain configuration by `make xconfig` or  `make O=outputX xconfig`, the xconfig window open but when I click on an option (for example Toolchain), nothing appear on the right section so I can't configure buildroot.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?
How can I do to reinstall xconfig?

Foundly

Comment: Works fine here. Where did you download Buildroot from? Can you try with a clean copy of Buildroot? If using git: `git clean -xdf && git reset --hard && git checkout 2020.02 && make xconfig`. If using a tarball, re-extract it into an empty directory.

Comment: I download buildroot with this command : git clone https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot . I try the clean copy but the results was the same. Thanks for your answer anyway.